# What is ballista arrow impact zone?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I made second entry to my fort as 1x100 tile long corridor, at the end of it I have ballista installed. It uses bronze ballista arrows.
With first arrow, 10-15 goblins killed, but second arrow misses most of remaining after first arrow goblins.

1. What are rules for flying ballista arrows?
2. Will it hit lying target? (for example if first arrow demolished legs, or creature collapsed from injuries)
3. If several creatures occupie one tile, will it hit all of them or only standing one?

Comment: Regarding point 2, do you *really* need to hit the goblins twice? Actually, don't answer that. I know how dwarfish engineering works.

Comment: @Studoku, ideally, i want to make goblins dead remotely, so my civilans can collect loot without being spooked by still alive remains.

Comment: @studoku Repeat after me: "There is no "overkill" There is only "Open fire" and "reload" -- or if you're a dwarven fortress engineer, there is only "Open the magma gates!"

Comment: This is why I love the "dwarf-fortress" tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unknown at this time, experimentation is key!
2. Yes, keep firing!
3. Yes! Die goblins die!

Spoilers ahoy!

> Watch out when goblins are 'half down' or dead ones lying around while still firing as someone might try and loot them - ballista's don't care who they hit!